# OneHotEncoding Mapping

Tags: scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

To discretize categorical features I'm using a LabelEncoder and OneHotEncoder. I know that LabelEncoder maps data alphabetically, but how does OneHotEncoder map data?

I have a pandas dataframe, `dataFeat` with 5 different columns, and 4 possible labels, like above. 
`dataFeat = data[['Feat1', 'Feat2', 'Feat3', 'Feat4', 'Feat5']]`

```
Feat1  Feat2  Feat3  Feat4  Feat5
  A      B      A      A      A
  B      B      C      C      C
  D      D      A       A     B
  C      C      A       A     A
```

I apply a `labelencoder` like this,

```
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

intIndexed = dataFeat.apply(le.fit_transform)
```

This is how the labels are encoded by the LabelEncoder

```
Label   LabelEncoded
 A         0
 B         1
 C         2
 D         3
```

I then apply a OneHotEncoder like this

```
enc = OneHotEncoder(sparse = False)

encModel = enc.fit(intIndexed)

dataFeatY = encModel.transform(intIndexed)
```

`intIndexed.shape = 94,5` and `dataFeatY.shape=94,20` .

I am a bit confused with the shape of `dataFeatY` - shouldn't it also be 95,5?

Following MhFarahani answer below, I have done this to see how labels are mapped

```
import numpy as np

S = np.array(['A', 'B','C','D'])
le = LabelEncoder()
S = le.fit_transform(S)
print(S)

[0 1 2 3]

ohe = OneHotEncoder()
one_hot = ohe.fit_transform(S.reshape(-1,1)).toarray()
print(one_hot.T)

[[ 1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.]]
```

Does this mean that labels are mapped like this, or is it different for each column ? (which would explain the shape being 94,20)

```
Label   LabelEncoded    OneHotEncoded
 A         0               1.  0.  0.  0
 B         1               0.  1.  0.  0.
 C         2               0.  0.  1.  0.
 D         3               0.  0.  0.  1.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One hot encoding means that you create vectors of one and zero. So the order does not matter. 
In `sklearn`, first you need to encode the categorical data to numerical data and then feed them to the `OneHotEncoder`, for example:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

S = np.array(['b','a','c'])
le = LabelEncoder()
S = le.fit_transform(S)
print(S)
ohe = OneHotEncoder()
one_hot = ohe.fit_transform(S.reshape(-1,1)).toarray()
print(one_hot)
```

which results in:

```
[1 0 2]

[[ 0.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.]]
```

But `pandas` directly convert the categorical data:

```
import pandas as pd
S = pd.Series( {'A': ['b', 'a', 'c']})
print(S)
one_hot = pd.get_dummies(S['A'])
print(one_hot)
```

which outputs:

```
A    [b, a, c]
dtype: object

   a  b  c
0  0  1  0
1  1  0  0
2  0  0  1
```

as you can see during the mapping, for each categorical feature a vector is created. The elements of the vectors are one at the location of the categorical feature and zero every where else. Here is an example when there are only two categorical features in the series:

```
S = pd.Series( {'A': ['a', 'a', 'c']})
print(S)
one_hot = pd.get_dummies(S['A'])
print(one_hot)
```

results in:

```
A    [a, a, c]
dtype: object

   a  c
0  1  0
1  1  0
2  0  1
```

**EDITS TO ANSWER THE NEW QUESTION**

Lets start with this question: Why do we perform a one hot encoding? IF you encode a categorical data like ['a','b','c'] to integers [1,2,3] (e.g. with LableEncoder), in addition to encoding your categorical data, you would give them some weights as 1 < 2 < 3. This way of encoding is fine for some machine learning techniques like RandomForest. But many machine learning techniques would assume that in this case 'a' < 'b' < 'c' if you encoded them with 1, 2, 3 respectively. In order to avoid this issue, you can create a column for each unique categorical variable in your data. In other words, you create a new feature for each categorical variables (here one column for 'a' one for 'b' and one for 'c'). The values in these new columns are set to one if the variable was in that index and zero in other places.

For the array in your example, the one hot encoder would be:

```
features ->  A   B   C   D 

          [[ 1.  0.  0.  0.]
           [ 0.  1.  0.  0.]
           [ 0.  0.  1.  0.]
           [ 0.  0.  0.  1.]]
```

You have 4 categorical variables "A", "B", "C", "D". Therefore, OneHotEncoder would populate your (4,) array to (4,4) to have one vector (or column) for each categorical variable (which will be your new features). Since "A" the 0 element of your array, the index 0 of your first column is set to 1 and the rest are set to 0. Similarly, the second vector (column) belongs to feature "B" and since "B" was in the index 1 of your array, the index 1 of the "B" vector is set to 1 and the rest are set to zero. The same applies for the rest of features.

Let me change your array. Maybe it can help you to better understand how label encoder works:

```
S = np.array(['D', 'B','C','A'])
S = le.fit_transform(S)
enc = OneHotEncoder()
encModel = enc.fit_transform(S.reshape(-1,1)).toarray()
print(encModel)
```

now the result is the following. Here the first column is 'A' and since it was last element of your array (index = 3), the last element of first column would be 1.

```
features ->  A   B   C   D
          [[ 0.  0.  0.  1.]
           [ 0.  1.  0.  0.]
           [ 0.  0.  1.  0.]
           [ 1.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Regarding your pandas dataframe, `dataFeat`, you are wrong even in the first step about how `LableEncoder` works. When you apply `LableEncoder` it fits to each column at the time and encode it; then, it goes to the next column and make a new fit to that column. Here is what you should get:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
df =  pd.DataFrame({'Feat1': ['A','B','D','C'],'Feat2':['B','B','D','C'],'Feat3':['A','C','A','A'],
                    'Feat4':['A','C','A','A'],'Feat5':['A','C','B','A']})
print('my data frame:')
print(df)

le = LabelEncoder()
intIndexed = df.apply(le.fit_transform)
print('Encoded data frame')
print(intIndexed)
```

results:

```
my data frame:
  Feat1 Feat2 Feat3 Feat4 Feat5
0     A     B     A     A     A
1     B     B     C     C     C
2     D     D     A     A     B
3     C     C     A     A     A

Encoded data frame
   Feat1  Feat2  Feat3  Feat4  Feat5
0      0      0      0      0      0
1      1      0      1      1      2
2      3      2      0      0      1
3      2      1      0      0      0
```

Note that in the first column `Feat1` 'A' is encoded to 0 but in second column `Feat2` the 'B' element is 0. This happens since `LableEncoder` fits to each column and transform it separately. Note that in your second column among ('B', 'C', 'D') the variable 'B' is alphabetically superior.

And finally, here is what you are looking for with `sklearn`:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

encoder = OneHotEncoder()
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
data_lable_encoded = df.apply(label_encoder.fit_transform).as_matrix()
data_feature_onehot = encoder.fit_transform(data_lable_encoded).toarray()
print(data_feature_onehot)
```

which gives you:

```
[[ 1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.]]
```

if you use `pandas`, you can compare the results and hopefully gives you a better intuition:

```
encoded = pd.get_dummies(df)
print(encoded)
```

result:

```
     Feat1_A  Feat1_B  Feat1_C  Feat1_D  Feat2_B  Feat2_C  Feat2_D  Feat3_A  \
0        1        0        0        0        1        0        0        1   
1        0        1        0        0        1        0        0        0   
2        0        0        0        1        0        0        1        1   
3        0        0        1        0        0        1        0        1   

     Feat3_C  Feat4_A  Feat4_C  Feat5_A  Feat5_B  Feat5_C  
0        0        1        0        1        0        0  
1        1        0        1        0        0        1  
2        0        1        0        0        1        0  
3        0        1        0        1        0        0
```

which is exactly the same!

Comment: Thanks @MhFarahani , I understand more now. I have updated my post with a more specific question.  :) I do not want to use `get_dummies` as I want to be able to use my trained model on different datasets

Comment: Usually, people encode their categorical data first and then split them to train and test data set. I edited my answer to make it more clear. Your understanding about how `LableEncoder` works on a data frame is wrong.

Comment: excellent answer, thank you! I was under the impression that `LabelEncoder` was fitting on the whole dataframe,rather than column by column.  I now understand how both `LabelEncoder` and `OneHotEncoder` works. So if I wanted to ensure that further separate data is encoded in the same way, do I just save the fitted `LabelEncoder` and `OneHotEncoder` objects for future use?

Comment: If you pickle your encoders, you would be able to use it. You need to import the `pickle` and dump your encoders there. But be careful with the `LableEncoder`. It would only keep the fit to the last column of  your dataframe!