# logistic regression feature value normalization in scikit-learn

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

Using Python 2.7. The question is about fit method. Question is for features (provided by parameter `X`), if there are non-numeric features (e.g. string type features, like `Male`, `Female`), do I need, or it is recommended to convert into numeric features (for performance and other reasons)? And also if I have multi-value string type features (e.g. feature geo could be any value of `San Francisco`, `San Jose`, `Mountain View`, etc.)

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.fit

regards,
Lin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must encode categorical features and convert them to numerical values, if you want to use `sklearn`. This apples to all `sklearn` estimators (including `LogisticRegression`) and it does not matter which version of python you are using.

look at **4.3.4. Encoding categorical features** of http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#encoding-categorical-features for more information.

Comment: Thanks MhFarahani, not sure if prediction results will change if I encode male/female into 0/1 or -1/1?

Comment: Also, I read some examples on encoding, but still feel confused, for example, from this link (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder), are these values -- `[0, 0, 3], [1, 1, 0], [0, 2, 1], [1, 0, 2]` representing 4 samples and each of them have 3 features? If so, confused why the document said `three features and two samples`?

Comment: 0/1 for male/female is a reasonable choice. But 1/1 will give you wrong results as it indicates that there is no difference between male and female. If you pass your features to `sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder`, it will encode your categorical features automatically.

Comment: Thanks MhFarahani, I mean -1 for man and 1 for women, not 1 for both man and women. If I encode male as 1 and female as 0, or I can encode male as -1 and female as 1, whether the two mechanisms have impact on prediction results?

Comment: The link that you mentioned is for `OneHotEncoding` which is different from just encoding categorical variable to numerical variables. Few days ago, I write a very long answer with several examples on how ro use both `LabelEncoder` and `OneHotEncoder`. I think it will help you to understand how they work. You can find it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38978853/onehotencoding-mapping/38988510#38988510

Comment: It depends on the estimator that you are using. For instance a DecisionTree most probably gives you a similar result. -1/1 is still not a bad choice. You should not for instance encode them to 100/1.

Comment: Thanks MhFarahani, studied your code today in the other post and it iss really wonderful (much better than scikit-learn samples. :)))! I just have one confusion about your code `S.reshape(-1,1)`, the confusion is if you reshape to `-1, 1`, but why output is only `0` and `1`? For output, I mean,

`[[ 0.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.]]`

Comment: Another quick question is, I studied `OneHotEncoding` today, I think it is just encode categorial variable (e.g. `male`, `female`) into numerical values (of `0` and `1`), but you said `OneHotEncoding` "is different from just encoding categorical variable to numerical variables", could you help to clarify what is the differences? Thanks.

Comment: I responded to you in a chat. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Hi MhFarahani, I think your chat answers my question, mark your reply as answer.

Comment: Hi MhFarahani, there is one thing I do not quite catch in your example is, I think your example of using LabelEncoder+OneHotEncoder is good enough, why bothering using pandas?
I mean this example (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38978853/onehotencoding-mapping/38988510#38988510)
Wondering if pandas could provide any additional functionalities comparing to using LabelEncoder+OneHotEncoder? Thanks.

Comment: BTW, MhFarahani you mentioned -- the first column is 'black', the second column is 'green', the third column is for 'red', I am wondering how OneHotEncoder choose to make black for first, green for second and red for third? Why not the other orders like black for 2nd, green for 3rd and red for the first? I know there is no key functional differences, just wonder how underlying works.

Comment: First, you need to encode the categorical features with LabelEncoder to numerical values.There black was 0, green was 1 and red was 2 (alphabetically). You will use this encoded numerical values as your OneHotEncoder inputs. Since Black was encoded to 0, it was the first column in your one hot encoded matrix.

Comment: Regarding your question about `Pandas.get_dummies` vs `LabelEncoding + OneHotEncoder`, they give you the same results. You can pick the one that you are more comfortable with it.

Comment: Thanks MhFarahani, so LabelEncoder will alphabetically encoded strings? Is it a documented feature? Or could be implementation dependent and could change by new versions of LabelEncoder implementation? In the document, it seems just mention encode string into number, not mention encode string in alphabetically order way. If I missed anything, please feel free to correct me.

Comment: `sklean` uses `numpy.unique()` function in its `LabelEncoder`. `numpy.unique()` returns the sorted unique elements of an array. Python (and thus Numpy) sorts the strings alphabetically.

Comment: Awesome, thanks MhFarahani. One last question, suppose I convert one dimensional string features into high dimensional 0/1 features using LabelEncoder and OneHotEncoder. But my other features are one dimensional scalar features, not sure if `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression` will work well to deal with both high dimensional features, and one dimension feature to fix one model? If not, what additional processing is needed?

Comment: This is the correct and highly recommended approach especially when you are using a linear model.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add a bit to MhFarahani's answer:
Yes, you need to convert those labels to numerical values (generally 0 or 1). For things like gender, you would want to have a row that has 0 for male and 1 for female, or vice versa. For something like geographical location, it'd be a bit more complicated. If there's a reasonable number of possible answers, you could use the get_dummies function in pandas (check the doc [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html)) to automatically populate your dataframe with rows to represent each possible location; you could then drop one of those rows to make that location the 'default'.

Comment: Thanks Barak, not sure if prediction results will change if I encode male/female into 0/1 or -1/1?

Comment: I assume you mean 0/1 or 1/0? (That is, you'll have a column called "gender", and the values will be either 1 or 0, with 1 being female and 0 being male OR 0 being female and 1 being male). The choice is arbitrary, but you should keep it mind when you see the results of the regression. For example, if the coefficient of gender is positive and 1 means male, then it means that being male has a positive effect on the dependent variable; if 1 means female, then being female has that positive effect!

Comment: Hi Barak, I mean if I encode male as 1 and female as 0, or I can encode male as -1 and female as 1, whether the two mechanisms have impact on prediction results?

Comment: Also, I read some examples on encoding, but still feel confused, for example, from this link (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder), are these values -- `[0, 0, 3], [1, 1, 0], [0, 2, 1], [1, 0, 2]` representing 4 samples and each of them have 3 features? If so, confused why the document said `three features and two samples`?