# How to one-hot-encode from a csv file input

Tags: python, csv, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a csv file which I read in with

```
import pandas
df = pd.read_csv("inputfile")
```

Some of the columns are numerical and some are strings.  Let's call one of the numerical columns `'num'` and one of the string ones `'col'`. I would like do the following:

1. I would like to be able to one-hot-encode a string column called `'col'` and result in a sparse matrix with all the features in it.
2. I would like to one-hot-encode `df['num']` but only when `df['num'] < 100`.

This is easy to do if the input were in a list of dictionaries.

*Step 1.* happens automatically when you run DictVectorizer

*Step 2.* just need me to iterate over the dictionaries adding a key/value pair for a new string feature `'num_cat'` when necessary and then run  DictVectorizer on the whole new list of dictionaries.

I am stuck on following:

- I need the matrix that results from the one-hot-encoding to be sparse. pd.get_dummies is very very slow if there are a large number of categories. Does it create a dense matrix and then make it sparse?  As a result I don't feel I can use that.
- Can I do what I need without first converting the data frame to a list of dictionaries and then running DictVectorizer? If not, is there an easy way to do the conversion?

Comment: Is the "col" only consist of categorical values? You can also use `OneHotEncoder` of sklearn. I do not know if it would be faster than `get_dommies`. Here are some examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38978853/onehotencoding-mapping/38988510#38988510

Answer (score 3):

Say you start with

```
In [31]: df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar'], 'num': [1, 1, 3, 213]})

In [32]: df
Out[32]: 
   col  num
0  foo    1
1  foo    1
2  bar    3
3  bar  213
```

First, let's take care of `col`:

If we define

```
In [33]: d = dict([e[:: -1] for e in enumerate(df.col.unique())])
```

Then we can use it to "numerify" `col`:

```
In [34]: df.col = df.col.map(d)

In [35]: df
Out[35]: 
   col  num
0    0    1
1    0    1
2    1    3
3    1  213
```

Now let's deal with `num`:

```
In [36]: import numpy as np
```

We'll just make everything over 100 into 100:

```
In [37]: df.num = np.minimum(df.num.values, 100)

In [38]: df
Out[38]: 
   col  num
0    0    1
1    0    1
2    1    3
3    1  100
```

Now for the encoding:

```
In [49]: from sklearn import preprocessing

In [50]: enc = preprocessing.OneHotEncoder()

In [51]: enc.fit(df.as_matrix()).transform(df.as_matrix()).toarray()
Out[51]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

Two things to note:

1. `toarray()` makes the matrix dense again; its use is optional, of course.
2. By construction, the last column is necessarily the "100 and over" category of `num`. You can retain it or drop this column, as needed.